# Data is not loading into one of the target tables

Tags: mapping, informatica

I have a mapping that loads data from 1 source table to five target tables.

4 tables will be loaded almost everytime when the workflow is ran and the and the fifth table will be loaded only when there is a null value in the required fields.

The data is loading properly to the four normal tables. But when there is a null value, it is not moving to the fifth table.

We have fixed some issues and deleted a normalizer which was not required in the mapping. But still, data is not moving to the fifth table.

We are able to see the data moving to the fifth table when we run a debugger but it is not doing the same when we run the workflow.

We are using Informatica Powercenter 10.2.
I have cross-checked if I forgot to check in anything but I checked in everything and still, we are facing this issue.

The data that should be moving to the fifth table is not going to any other table and it is just dropping out. I have looked at the verbose logs,
I found something similar to the log I pasted below:

```
Message Code    Message
TT_11115        [ROUTER]: Output Group Index = [0]

TT_11037        [TABLE 5 ERROR TABLE]: Output - 1,  Dropped - 0

TT_11037        [TABLE 1]: Output - 4,  Dropped - 0

TT_11037        [TABLE 2]: Output - 4,  Dropped - 0

TT_11037        [TABLE 3]: Output - 4,  Dropped - 0

TT_11037        [TABLE 4]: Output - 0,  Dropped - 0

TT_11031        Transformation [EXPRESSION]:

TT_11114        [EXPRESSION]: Input Group Index = [0], Input Row Count [1]

TT_11034        [ROUTER]: Input - 1

TT_11115        [EXPRESSION]: Output Group Index = [0]

TT_11037        [FILTER]: Output - 1,   Dropped - 0

TT_11031        Transformation [FILTER[version 1]]:

TT_11114        [FILTER]: Input Group Index = [0], Input Row Count [1]

TT_11034        [EXPRESSION]: Input - 1

TT_11115        [FILTER]: Output Group Index = [0]

TT_11037        [EXPRESSION 2]: Output - 0, Dropped - 0

TT_11031        Transformation [EXPRESSION 2[version 1]]:

TT_11114        [EXPRESSION 2]: Input Group Index = [0], Input Row Count [0]

TT_11034        [FILTER]: Input - 0

TT_11115        [EXPRESSION 2]: Output Group Index = [0]

TT_11037        [TARGET TABLE 5]: Output - 0,   Dropped - 0

TT_11033        Transformation to target [TARGET TABLE 5[version 6]]:

TT_11114        [TARGET TABLE 5]: Input Group Index = [0], Input Row Count [0]

TT_11034        [EXPRESSION 2]: Input - 0

TT_11038        Output - 0, Dropped - 0
```

The above logs show the pass-through of the data from the router to the table.
I could see the data is dropping out at some point but it is not shown anywhere as dropped. So, I cannot figure what is the issue here.

Comment: Hi - you haven’t really supplied any information that would enable someone to help you. Where does the record with null values go when you run the mapping? Have you turned up the logging level to verbose  data?

Comment: Please provide the logs or try running the mapping with `collect performance data` turned on and try either try to figure this out or provide more details.

Comment: Hi @NickW, I have added the verbose log to the supplied information. Let me know if you find anything that can cause the issue I am facing.